# how to border a table in html using css

Tags: html, css

I'm facing a problem with my table, it doesn't give to my `tr` row a border to separate my columns even if I put in my css

```
#mytable {
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
table,tr, td {
   border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work, my table is like this:

```
 <tr> 
     <td><?php echo $trouvé["lastname"] ?> </td>  
     <?php if ($trouvé["idsous_risques"] == 1) { ?>
     <td style="position:fixed;left:11.5%;border:0;"><?php echo '<center>' . $trouvé["nbr_sous_risques"] . '</center>' ?> </td>  
     <?php } ?>
</tr>
```

Comment: Post rendered html code for total table

Comment: maybe you have an empty table? It works here ..

Comment: Please don't use diacritic in variable names. Stick to the ASCII range of characters

Comment: thank you for your response but it's not an issue , my table is not empty

Answer (score 1):

If your table structure is fine then it should work with this css

```
<table id="mytable" cellpaddin="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr> 
     <td>test </td>      
     <td >test</td>       
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
#mytable {
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
td {
   border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uVecAHOl/1/edit)**

Comment: it doesn't work , i can't delete style from my <td> specialy my properties 'left' and position , ALSO I FORGOT TO SAY , that each row have 2 or 3 columns , the other columns are empty

Answer (score 0):

You can make your table in html using css like this code

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        table{ border:1px solid black }
        th{ border:1px solid red}
        td{border:1px solid green}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>S.No.</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Country</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Ross tylor</td>
            <td>Canada</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

See this code and make your table stylist.. if you have any problem then you can check from below link
http://www.webclasses.in/css-tables/

Answer (score -2):

I use:

```
border-style:solid;
border-width:1px;
border-color:#CCC;
```

Comment: That's exactly the same as specifying `border: 1px solid #ccc`.

Comment: doesn't work for me , i need to put a propety into a tr even if it contain juste one td